# Do vedas contain vyutpatti definitions to words?

Tags: vedas, meaning

Do Vedas contain the meaning/definition of (some) words? Are they called vyutpatti meanings?

Comment: By vedas do you mean Samhitas only?

Comment: @Pandya yeah, I mean only Samhitas. But if Samhitas does not contain, then it is okay to give an indication about the place containing those definitions, because, I have no knowledge about the content of Vedas.

Comment: That place is [Nirukta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nirukta) which is one of the six [Vedangas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vedanga).